# Irreducible factorization - Discrete Mathematics revision

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Q**

Determine the irreducible factorization of each of the following polynomials $f$ in the indeterminate $x$ over the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of integers module the prime $p$.

$f = x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ and $p=2$

**A so far**

$f(0) = 1$
$f(1) = 0$

Since $f(0)=0$ there is a linear factor $(x-1)$ and hence $f$ is not irreducible.

---

This is from a past exam paper I am using for revision without any solutions.

In all previous exam papers for this question there has never been a root thus having to find a irreducible factorization for example:

$f = x^5 + x^3 + 1$ and $p=2$

$f(0) = 1 = f(1)$

Hence there are no linear factors of $f$ however since $deg(f) = 5$ we need to look for a irreducible quadratic*irreducible cubic

=> Irreducible quadratic in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ = $(x^2+x+1)$

=> Irreducible cubic in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ = $(x^3+x^2+1)$ or $(x^3+x+1)$

Clearly $(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1) \neq f$ and $(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1) \neq f$
so $f$ is irreducible.

---

How do I handle the rest of the above question? It seems to 'easy' for what is supposed to be the harder question of the 3 (3 polynomials i,ii and iii where i and ii are worth 3 marks and iii is worth 4 marks).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For quintics without root, you need only divide by $x^2+x+1$. Even for sextics without root, after finding indivisibility by $x^2+x+1$, the only remaining possibility (unless the thing is a manifest square) is that your sextic is product of the two cubic irreducibles, and you need only divide by one of them. For my money, Euclidean division is easier than multiplication of polynomials, in this context.

Comment: @Lubin I know how to deal with quintics without roots (as i've explained in the question) but how do i deal with quintics with roots? or it is as simple as saying there is a root hence it is irreducible and that's all there is to it?

Comment: You mean reducible. If it has a root $a$, it’s automatically divisible by $x-a$. You learned that in high school, I hope.

Comment: @Lubin yes sorry typo in my comment. So if there is a root we can say $f$ is not irreducible (reducible) and leave it at that?

Comment: Most certainly.